# waitpid() always returns '-1'

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork, waitpid

I got an assignment to make unix-like shell in C.
The user can input "procs" which prints all running processes, and before executing this function, I must use the function "updateProcessList" which traverses the list of processes and with the help of waitpid() updates the processes' status. If a processes "freshly" terminated I must delete this processes from the list (still didn't implement it).
The problem I encounter is with the update function. Every call for waitpid() returns -1 with error number '10' which means that no child processes of the given id exists under the parent, which is not true of course (this child exists in a zombie state) and even a running process like "sleep 5 &" (the '&' means that it's non-blocking, thus the parent won't be blocked) is not found.
The man page is pretty hard to understand, and the explanation of the assignment in this particular section is pretty crappy (till now I've done everything by myself with the help of the manual pages, but for this one I'm lost, spent already several hours and I'm stuck).
I would be really glad if someone can pinpoint what I'm missing here.
Thanks!

```
#include "LineParser.h"
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define TERMINATED  -1
#define RUNNING 1
#define SUSPENDED 0
#define SIZE 2048
#define FORKED(x) (strcmp(x, "cd") != 0 && strcmp(x, "procs") != 0)
int debugMode = 0;

typedef struct process{
    cmdLine* cmd;                         /* the parsed command line*/
    pid_t pid;                        /* the process id that is running the command*/
    int status;                           /* status of the process: RUNNING/SUSPENDED/TERMINATED */
    struct process *next;                     /* next process in chain */
} process;

process **processList;


void updateProcessStatus(process* process_list, int pid, int status) {
    process* temp = process_list;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp -> pid == pid) {
            temp -> status = pid;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}

void updateProcessList(process **process_list) {
    int status;
    process **curr = process_list;
    while ((*curr) !=  NULL) {
        pid_t statusChangedId = waitpid((*curr) -> pid, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        if (statusChangedId == -1) {
            perror("");
            printf("%d\n", errno);
            printf("%d\n", (*curr) -> pid);
        }
        if (statusChangedId > 0) {
            updateProcessStatus(*curr, statusChangedId, status);
        }
        curr = &((*curr) -> next);
    }
}


void addProcess(process** process_list, cmdLine* cmd, pid_t pid) {
    process **tail = process_list;
    while (*tail != NULL) {
        tail = &((*tail) -> next);
    }
    *tail = (process *) malloc(sizeof(process));
    (*tail) -> cmd = cmd;
    (*tail) -> pid = pid;
    (*tail) -> status = RUNNING;
    (*tail) -> next = NULL;
}


void printProcessList(process** process_list) {
    updateProcessList(process_list);
    process *curr = *process_list;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        printf("%-13s%-13s%s\n", "PID", "Command", "STATUS");
        printf("%-13d%-13s%s\n", curr -> pid, curr -> cmd -> arguments[0], 
                                                                        (curr -> status) == -1 ? "TERMINATED" :
                                                                        (curr -> status) == 0 ? "SUSPENDED" :
                                                                                                "RUNNING");
        curr = curr -> next;
    }
}


void execute(cmdLine *pCmdLine) {
    if (!FORKED(pCmdLine -> arguments[0])) {
        if (strcmp(pCmdLine -> arguments[0], "cd") == 0) {
            if (chdir(pCmdLine -> arguments[1]) < 0) {
                perror("");
                fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", errno);
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(pCmdLine -> arguments[0], "procs") == 0) {
            printProcessList(processList);
        }
        free(pCmdLine);
    } 
    else {
        // if we're here, it means user input wasn't "cd" nor "procs"
        pid_t id = fork();
        if (id == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fork() couldn't open child, terminating...");
            _exit(-1);
        }
        if (id != 0) {                                                  // this is the parent and it will be blocked if needed
            addProcess(processList, pCmdLine, id);
            if (pCmdLine -> blocking) {
                waitpid(id, NULL, 0);
            }
        }
        else {
            execvp(pCmdLine -> arguments[0], pCmdLine -> arguments);
            perror("Error ");                                           // returns here only if execv encounterd some error
            _exit(errno);
        }
    }
    //_exit(0);
    if (debugMode) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process ID: %d\nExecuting command: %s\n", getpid(), pCmdLine -> arguments[0]);
    }
    // if (!FORKED(pCmdLine -> arguments[0]))
    //     freeCmdLines(pCmdLine);

}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    processList = (process **) malloc(4);
    char cmdBuffer[SIZE];
    char cwdName[PATH_MAX];

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0) {
            debugMode = 1;
        }
    }
    getcwd(cwdName, PATH_MAX);
    printf("%s\n", cwdName);
    while (fgets(cmdBuffer, SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (strncmp(cmdBuffer, "quit", 4) == 0) {
            break;
        }
        cmdLine* currCmd = parseCmdLines(cmdBuffer);
        execute(currCmd);
    }

    freeProcessList(*processList);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  I don't think what you show is 'minimal'.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `pCmdLine -> blocking` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `pCmdLine->blocking`.

Comment: Which of the calls to `waitpid()` are you referring to?

Comment: It's not related to your issue, but I advise you not to use `errno` as an exit status.  Error numbers are meant for use by functions within the same process to communicate status information, not for programs to communicate with the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, your suggestions are noted.
Referring to Jonathans question, the waitpid() in the 'updateProcessList' functions.  
Basically, this is how it goes: The user enters a command, then, if it is not "cd" or "procs" I call fork() and let the child execute the command. The parent saves the process in the processList, and when called "procs" it should print all processes and their state. Before printing, I should use waitpid() (the one I mentioned above) and check for updated status from the children. Hope it clears some things.

Comment: If `waitpid()` is returning -1 and setting `errno` to `ECHILD` when you pass it the pid of an existing process then the most likely cause is that the process whose status you are asking about is not a child of the process in which `waitpid()` is called.  It's not immediately clear to me how that would arise in the program presented, but it should be easy enough to check.

Comment: This is pretty strange since the only one that can call this particular waitpid() is the parent. The children that are made are executed, and as far as I know, "exec*" exits the process if no errors occurred, and if an error occurred, I manually use _exit() on the forked process. Thus only the parent has access to the waitpid() that always return -1.

Comment: You can't `waitpid` twice on a process, can you? You are calling `waitpid` on a process that ended multiple times, are you? | Subjective: ugh, that indentation of `->` with spaces is hard to read. An that `(*tail) -> ` is hard to read. I would advise to consider removing spaces around `->`.

Comment: About the conventions, I got it that I'm doing it wrong and noted it.
About my problem, I'm making progress I think.. I have a question:
If a child of a parent finished its execution successfully before the parent could call waitpid(), what happens to the child? Does it become a zombie process? Because I noticed that when a child process exits successfully before the parent called waitpid(), the return value is -1 and the child is not found.

Comment: Both `wait()` and `waitpid()` return when there's a dead child (or a stopped or traced child with `waitpid()`) to be reported on.  The dead child becomes a zombie until it is waited for.  If a zombie's parent exits without waiting for it, the zombie is transferred to PID 1 (classically), and that process spends almost all its time waiting for (inherited) children to die.  So, `waitpid()` normally only reports on dead children.  It won't report on running children.

Comment: In `main()`, you do `processList = (process **) malloc(4);` — what does that 4 represent?  It is normal to use `sizeof(*processList) * 4`, for example, to allocate an array of 4 `process *` values.  It also isn't obvious why `processList` is a `process **`; I would expect it to be a `process *` (the head of a list of `process` structures, or the first element of an array of `process` structures).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler about the first comment, for example when I write "ls" if is executed and becomes a zombie, and when calling "waitpid()" for this process I receive the error that such child doesn't exist (when I create this process, it is in RUNNING state, it won't update after it is finished).
On the other hand, when writing "sleep 5&" ('&' means non blocking) and immediately write "procs" - waitpid() doesn't return any error. After 5 seconds, writing "procs" again - the process updates successfully (means that waitpid() returned that the process is terminated).

Comment: Continuation:
It's strange that I don't get any update with waitpid() about the "ls" command for example that is finished before the parent calls waitpid().
About the second question, I just wrote 4 because we work in a 32bit system, so it is the size of a pointer.. Just out of laziness.. Should be (process *) as you've mentioned.
And about the double pointers, this is what I was given.. not my choice.

Comment: Since we don't have the `parseCmdLines()` function or the header, we can't run your code.  You don't need to provide that code; you can carefully initialize a set of structures that contain information equivalent to what `parseCmdLines()` would return — that's a part of creating an MCVE.  Until we can run the code, there isn't much more we can do to help.